# Magento 1.9 : Need New Currency Update Module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, currency

Magento 1.9 currency module no longer works as finance.google.com doesn't return anything anymore... *sigh*

Does anyone know a good free module I can install which will replicate this currency update functionality?

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=Currency#q=Currency&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products&p=0&fR%5Bext_all_editions%5D%5B0%5D=Community&fR%5Bext_platform%5D%5B0%5D=Magento%201&nR%5Bprice.USD.default%5D%5B%3C%3D%5D%5B0%5D=0&nR%5Bvisibility_search%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1&is_v=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are many modules available in the marketplace, which use different conversion services, you can try below module:

https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_Fixerio

because the same API has been implemented by Magento team in Magento 2.

If you are a developer, then you can also check below link to implement Openexchangerates services:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/adding-openexchangerates-currency-conversion-service-to-magento/

Please let me know if you have any other query regarding the same.